# Remove lines with identical extension inside every <title> tag - Regular Expression

Tags: regex, notepad++, archive, winrar

I create a Report List with Winrar. 
Inside this list i have a text list like this

```
<tag>Adventures of Shuggy</tag>
!Shuggy.png
!Sound Bank.txt
4.lwav
5.lwav
6.lwav
88.lwav
89.lwav
<tag>Adventures of Jack</tag>
90.lwav
91.lwav
92.lwav
93.lwav
!Sound Bank.xsb
```

I want remove duplicates extensions *inside every tag*  and have a text like this:

```
<tag>Adventures of Shuggy</tag>
!Shuggy.png
!Sound Bank.txt
4.lwav
<tag>Adventures of Jack</tag>
90.lwav
!Sound Bank.xsb
```

or even better

```
<tag>Adventures of Shuggy</tag>
.png
.txt
.lwav
 <tag>Adventures of Jack</tag>
.xsb
```

Is there a regular expression to use on notepad++ to remove **lines with identical** *.txt* or identical *.lwav* inside every tag like `<title>`?
 Can i use excel for this?

Comment: can i use excel for what? lol (: -- ignore my ignorance, i'm not an excel user

Comment: Those aren’t inside tags, they’re after the tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tossed this up real quick. Should work fine in notepad++. Make sure to set the global flag (if there is one) and the multiline one.

```
/^.+(\.[^.]+)$(?=\s*(?:(?!<tag>)[^.])+\1)|^(?!<tag>)[^.]+/gm
```

You should (most likely) not use the flags and delimiters like I have above. I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Explanation + demo : http://regex101.com/r/lC0lD1